# Adding Helper Rails Methods to a Directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I've created a pdfs directory in `app/` for invoices and purchase orders (I'm using prawn). Naturally, I want the `NumberHelper` to be available. Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: And in your pdfs directory you have simple classes that uses prawn to generate your pdfs, right?

Comment: Yes, correct...

Comment: Would you please accept the answer if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could

```
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
```

in the classes you use to generate the pdfs